# Convert Mac Address to Integer

Tags: java, android

Im trying convert mac adress to integer:

Result is: 2321591092112814

It should be: 255771439995918

Im trying:

```
String[] macAddressParts = device.getAddress().split(":");

Byte[] macAddressBytes = new Byte[6];
String macAddressString = "";

for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
   Integer hex = Integer.parseInt(macAddressParts[i], 16);
   macAddressString += hex.toString();

}
System.out.println(macAddressString);

// 2321591092112814
```

Comment: How are you getting the result?  How do you get from a byte array to that output?

Comment: I linked hex as a string, but it doesn't give me the desired result.

Comment: Show us code.  "I linked hex as a string" is not enough information, and it's very possible that the bug is in _that_ code, not the code you've shown us.  Show us the exact code that "linked hex as a string."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make an integer by catenating strings.

Try that :

```
String[] macAddressParts = "e8:9f:6d:d3:1c:0e".split(":");

Byte[] macAddressBytes = new Byte[6];
long addressAsInteger = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    Integer hex = Integer.parseInt(macAddressParts[i], 16);
    addressAsInteger = addressAsInteger * 256 + hex;
}
System.out.println("Addresse as an integer : " + addressAsInteger);
```

It gives the right answer : 255771439995918.